# What is "jobs" commmand in Redhat Linux

Tags: shell, command, jobs

What is `jobs` command in Linux and how to use it?
Please give some example.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `jobs` is a built-in command in your shell. If you are using `bash` then run `man bash` and search for `jobs` at the beginning of the line (press `/` to start searching and then `^ *jobs`). You should see the following:

```
jobs [-lnprs] [ jobspec ... ]
jobs -x command [ args ... ]
        The first form lists the active jobs.  The options have the  following  meanings:
        -l     List process IDs in addition to the normal information.
        -n     Display information only about jobs that have changed status since the
               user was last notified of their status.
        -p     List only the process ID of the job's process group leader.
        -r     Restrict output to running jobs.
        -s     Restrict output to stopped jobs.
```

A simple example of `jobs` output:

```
$ jobs
[1]  - running    firefox-bin
[2]  + running    emacs .zshrc
```